# Slow boot up on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, log

I'm a new ubuntu user and I love it! However my boot time is very slow (about 95 ceconds). I've managed to create a boot log, and there are some points in the boot up where there seem to be conflicts. I don't understand a word of it, but I've put all the conflict (or what seems to be problem bits) here. If you could give  me any guidance at all to speed this up, I'd be very grateful. JF

```
[    1.896019] pci 0000:00:1a.7: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
[    3.496019] pci 0000:00:1d.7: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
[    3.496289] PCI: CLS 64 bytes, default 64
[    3.496384] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...

[    4.114225] Simple Boot Flag value 0x5 read from CMOS RAM was invalid

[    4.158020] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for AC is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[
[    4.167543] GHES: HEST is not enabled!

[    4.168300] ACPI: Deprecated procfs I/F for battery is loaded, please retry with CONFIG_ACPI_PROCFS_POWER cleared
[    4.168307] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[
[    6.281587] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[    8.786283] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   12.784043] raid6: sse2x1    3565 MB/s
[   
[   14.926967] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[   14.926972] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   17.075511] EXT4-fs (sda1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[   17.147692] EXT4-fs (sda1): 9 orphan inodes deleted
[   17.147697] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[   17.330067] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   38.377388] Adding 2085884k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2085884k FS
[   38.702616] init: bootchart main process (359) terminated with status 127
[   38.809676] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   38.849901] systemd-udevd[385]: starting version 204
[   38.978070] lp: driver loaded but no devices found

[   39.532190] init: Failed to spawn bluetooth main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[   39.543198] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   39.611276] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMBA 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   39.611286] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   39.611291] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   39.611295] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   39.611297] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   39.611301] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   39.611302] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich

[   42.841244] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[   42.876715] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[   43.336276] init: Failed to spawn atd main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[   43.633661] zram: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
45.525504] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3

[   47.575983] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1627) terminated with status 1
[   47.577829] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   61.964041] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   62.289561] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (2065) terminated with status 1
[   69.935123] audit_printk_skb: 42 callbacks suppressed

[   69.935138] type=1400 audit(1519310402.179:27): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2101 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   84.243764] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth2: link up
[   84.243787] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth2: link becomes ready
[   89.372233] init: Failed to spawn nmbd main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[  155.131455] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth2 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:48:8d:36:a9:40:68:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

Comment: Are you saying 95 seconds from poweron to login screen? Or 95 seconds from poweron to full, useful desktop?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of both `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame`. For an average system from poweron to full desktop, 95 seconds does not seem excessive to me,

Comment: It appears the swap file is taking too long to mount. As it is essentially an empty partition it should be instantaneous. For example on my system it takes less than a second, on yours it appears to take 11 seconds.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. It takes about 100 seconds from LXLE logo to full operational desktop. I thought that was a very long time, but maybe that's not unusual if you reckon that's pretty fast? Is there a simple way I can make the swap file mount quicker. thanks very  much